# Finding the range in C

Tags: c, function, range

So within my program I have written a function that finds the range of a set of numbers, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Instead of giving me the difference between the smallest number and the biggest number, its giving me this:

```
(3) Range
(4) Restart/Exit
3
7900455959466841600000000000000000.0
```

I've looked all over the internet, and while I found a couple useful examples of how to do it, they didn't seem to fix this problem. Here is my function, if anyone needs to see the entire code, just let me know.

```
 float range(float numbers[], int amount)
 {
  int i;
  float diff=0;
  for (i=1;i<=amount;i++){

      diff=numbers[amount]-numbers[1];
  }

      printf("%.1f",diff);

      return diff;
   }
```

I've tried everything I can think of, any suggestions

Comment: C arrays are zero-indexed.  Assuming you're using the normal semantics of `amount` representing the number of elements in `numbers`, your code reads past the end of the array.  Besides that, why bother with the loop at all? You overwrite `diff` on every pass through the loop.

Comment: Is there a better way to go about this without the loop?

Comment: You seem to assume that the numbers were sorted: that the largest index would hold the largest number etc. (also note what Carl said)  Instead you should use to loop to 'find' the largest && the smallest number, both of which require just a single temporary variable.

Comment: The problem is your loop is not even doing anything.  You're not using the loop index in any way.

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 - if you have another question please ask it as a separate question.  Overwriting this one makes it lose all context for the answers which is both confusing and unhelpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
float range(float numbers[], int amount)
{
    int i;
    float min, max, diff;
    min = numbers[0];
    max = numbers[0];
    for (i=1; i < amount; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] < min) min = numbers[i];
        if (max < numbers[i]) max = numbers[i];
    }

    diff = max - min;

    printf("%.1f",diff);

    return diff;
}
```

Comment: that fixed it. I'm not real sure what went wrong because in an earlier version of this program, what I had actually worked. After tweaking a few things, it seemed to go crazy. I appreciate your services sir. You are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please click on the Tick beside the answer that you deem to be the correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If your array is ordered, the problem is simplified to:

```
/* assuming ammount point to the last position of the array */
return numbers[ammount] - numbers[0]
```

If the array is not ordered, you have to build a loop to take the maximum and minimum element of the array to return its difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your amount variable is better named highestIndex

In order to fix your code I can see two things you might do:

1). Understand what your current code is doing. Try "desk checking". On paper ( or in your mind ) invent some input to this function.

```
 numbers = [ 2, 17, 4, 10];  amount = 3;

 i = 1, is 1 <=3 ? yes, OK go into the body

 diff = numbers[3] - numbers[1] which is 10 - 17, so diff is now -7

 increment i, i = 2, is 2 <=3 ? yes, OK go into the body

 diff = numbers[3] - numbers[2] which is 10 - 4, so diff is now 6

 increment i, i = 3, is 3 <=3 ? yes, OK go into the body

 diff = numbers[3] - numbers[2] which is 10 - 10, so diff is now 0

 increment i, i = 4, is 3 <=3 ? no. so leave the loop

 print diff ... hmmm it's 0 at the moment
```

The trick here is to pick a small example set and see whether the processing makes sense. Clearly this can't ever find the range, unless the input array is sorted, but in which case you need the loop, just subtract numbers[highestIndex] and numbers[0].

2). Now what do you need to do? The range is the difference between the biggest number and the smallest number in the list. So your code needs to look through the list and find the biggest and smallest number. Try starting like this

initialise candidate values, note that this is correct if your list has only one member, then the biggest and smallest are the same, the only value in the list

```
  float biggest = numbers[0];
  float smallest = numbers[0];
```

then loop through looking to see whether any of the other numbers are bigger or smaller than your current biggest and smallest.

```
  for ( int i = 1; i <= highestIndex; i++ ) {

         is numbers[i] bigger than biggest
               set new biggest value

         do the same sort of thing for smallest

  }

  print biggest - smallest
```

then for extra credit look at what happens if all the numbers are negative and what happens in special cases, read about what values a float can hold.